# Colorbox load new PHP-Page in DIV not works

Tags: jquery, colorbox

That Works! Just with JQuery:

```
$('#myBlobBox').load('contents/test.php?action='+aAction+'&step='+tStep+'');
$('#myBlobBox').html('#myBlobBox');
```

And here my Colorbox example, but does not run. Why ?

```
$.('#myBlobBox').colorbox({load:\"'contents/test.php?action='+aAction+'&step='+tStep\"});
$.('#myBlobBox').colorbox({html:'#myBlobBox'})
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change it into, remove the escaped `\"`:

```
$.('#myBlobBox').colorbox({load:'contents/test.php?action='+aAction+'&step='+tStep});
```

or

```
$.('#myBlobBox').colorbox({load:"'contents/test.php?action='+aAction+'&step='+tStep"});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.colorbox({load:` ==> does not fit, I think

i have the same effect like the colorbox if i put this

```
$(this).colorbox.resize();
```

in my loaded PHP-Page.

Thanks a lot ;)